# Proper way to reset/cleanup a connection

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a very simple connection pooler in my application. When handing back a connection I need to ensure that no variables are set and no transaction is still on going. I understand that `ROLLBACK; DISCARD ALL;` should be enough.

In most cases, if the transaction was successful, it will be committed before handing it over to the pooler and at this point, I will have a warning such as `WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress`.

Is there any way to execute a `ROLLBACK` only if we are still in a transaction?
Or is there an other preferred method to cleanup a connection?

Comment: @Jasen Postgres 10. Just in case is there any way to disable this particular log? I would like to keep the other warning level logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming libpq, you can call [PQtransactionStatus](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-status.html#LIBPQ-PQTRANSACTIONSTATUS) to find out if there
's a transaction open.

If you only have SQL then you can call

```
select xact_start <> query_start from pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity where pid=pg_backend_pid();
```

That round-trip will add latency to the cleanup process, but this will not be a problem so long as there's no process blocked waiting for the freed connection.